# moment-timezone returns undefined while using embroider compat build in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, momentjs, ember-cli, moment-timezone, ember-cli-addons

[image]

**Original Error**
cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'load') error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'load')

[image]

created moment-timezone.d.ts file and type added for moment-timezone but not works

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)